# How to limit speed of sending mails with attachment via SMTP?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, limit, bandwidth

I'm sending mails with huge attachments via SMTP. This is blocking my bandwidth because there are many mails.
Is there any way to limit the speed to e.g. 512kb/s ?
This should only affect my program and/or the sending of each mail without adding a delay.

Comment: you could always introduce a delay between each item sent...

Comment: they have a delay, but i want to limit the sending itself because the files I'm sending are big

Answer (score 1):

If this were my task, I would approached it differently. Store the attachments on a cloud server (i.e. Dropbox), and just include a link to those files in the body of the email.